# Updated kernel to mainline (4.3.3), but apt-get upgrade keeps downloading headers & image for 4.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I have a Surface Pro 2 running ubuntu, and prior to kernel 4.x it's been quite problematic (wifi/trackpad/screen etc). I've been updating my kernel to mainline, first 4.0, then 4.2 and more recently 4.3.3 (I download 3x debs from kernel.org and install with dpkg). Each upgrade has brought many fixes, in fact now it's really solid (except for very rare difficulty waking up).

When I do `uname -r` I get `4.3.3-040303-generic`

However, when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the message:

```
Calculating upgrade... 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   
 linux-headers-4.2.0-22 linux-headers-4.2.0-22-generic 
 linux-headers-4.2.0-23 linux-headers-4.2.0-23-generic 
 linux-headers-4.2.0-24 linux-headers-4.2.0-24-generic 
 linux-headers-4.2.0-26 linux-headers-4.2.0-26-generic
 linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic linux-image-4.2.0-24-generic  
 linux-image-4.2.0-26-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic  
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-24-generic 
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-26-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-22-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-23-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-24-generic  
 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-26-generic 
 python-lzma python-parsley python-twisted python-twisted-conch 
 python-twisted-lore python-twisted-mail python-twisted-names
 python-twisted-news python-twisted-runner python-twisted-words python-txsocksx
 torsocks wmctrl 
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
```

So I do `sudo apt-get autoremove`, they're all removed, but after a while new debs for 4.2 are downloaded again. What am I doing wrong? Why are they being downloaded, do I need them, and how can I stop this?

Cheers,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because custom or unofficial kernels (including those from kernel.org as far as I know) are not within the scope of this site and therefore off-topic.

Comment: if I were having problems with the kernel then fair enough. But it's not the kernel I'm having problems with, but the behaviour of apt-get (or dpkg or something, I guess)

Comment: That's because you're receiving update from the kernel from the Official Ubuntu repository, nothing wrong here.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't realize current official kernel was at 4.2. thanks.